# Minecraft Shared Inventory Between Players in a LAN World

Tags: java, minecraft, inventory

The problem I am trying to solve is allowing all players to share the same inventory in a Minecraft LAN world. This means that if someone chops down a tree and gets wood, everyone will get that wood. If someone drops an item, the item will be removed from everyone's inventory. If someone is mining with a pick that's in slot 1 on the hotbar, it should be losing durability for everyone else. If someone rearranges items in the inventory, it should be rearranged for everyone else. Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to set everyone's inventory to the same object so that any modifications to the inventory is the same for everyone.

I have tried using NBTExplorer to copy inventories but that doesn't sync between players in realtime. I am also aware that there are server plugins that can have inventories synced to a database like MySQL, but I am almost certain there is an easier way to do this other than hosting a server and trying to set up a plugin and DB for this.

Is there a value I can modify that will cause all inventories to have the same seed? Can I use some command to generate a world with all player inventories pointing to one location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla commands post 1.13, you can do a simple command block loop, or use a datapack. These are the steps it would take:
-Set up a central chest minecart that will store the universal inventory
-Set up that inventory with a basic set of supplies
-Check for differences between each player's inventory and the chest minecart using the /execute unless command
-When this happens, /data merge the inventory of the chest minecart to every player

Data command tutorial: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=2ahUKEwj1noDl9pLnAhUEGc0KHdGxC00QwqsBMAB6BAgMEAU&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov
Execute command tutorial: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/execute#unless

I haven't come up with the exact commands for it yet, but this systems should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as just generating a seed or anything like that. You need to persist and transmit each and every inventory change, per player, to all players. And find a way to keep that in sync.

You'd probably be best off using a server side plugin, since this cannot be achieved on client-side only. Listen to any inventory events using a plugin listener, and then iterate over all players except the one who triggered the event, to perform the same operations on their inventory to keep all players in sync.